# Using ubuntu from a mac (alternatives to X11 forwarding + XQuartz?)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, remote-desktop, xorg, remote

What would you say is the latest/preferred way to connect from a mac to a linux box?

At the moment I am using X11 forwarding over a dedicated ethernet connection plus NFS shared folders.

My requirements are quite simple:

- Single independent windows / apps (I don't want a single full desktop)
- I don't care much about sound
- Reduce lag in some java/graphical apps

What I've tried so far:

- NX = v3 had single window support. Since v4 only full desktop is
  supported.
- VNC = brings the whole desktop
- FastX = very very expensive

What are people using nowadays?
Thanks for your answers/comments!

Comment: Although X2Go says that Ubuntu 14.04 is not supported, it seems to apply only to Unity. I switched to X2Go in Single application mode. I can launch a shell script that loads what I need (terminal, etc.). I am still interested in hearing other alternatives

Answer (score 1):

After trying different alternatives I end up using a combination of:

- NoMachine
- X2Go